# Python catching error in a superclass, and track it inside the child class

Tags: python, exception

I have been really bothered by something about error handling recently, and I have not successding in finding an answer on the internet :

Basically, I have most of my classes that are all descending from a superclass that handles different things.

I would like to do the error handling only once, in this superclass. The problem is : I don't know how to track the error to the child class !
The most detailed tracking tools I have found on the internet so far are :

```
exc_type, exc_obj,  tb = sys.exc_info()
f = tb.tb_frame
lineno = tb.tb_lineno
filename = f.f_code.co_filename
linecache.checkcache(filename)
line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
err_msg = 'Exception in ({}, line {} "{}"): {}'.format(filename, lineno, line.strip(), exc_obj)

traceback.print_stack()
```

But basically, it leads me only the the line of the superclass where I try to display it, so I don't know where it comes from and I end up using prints everywhere to track my error :/

so basically :

~==~ superclass ~==~

```
1 class MySuperClass(-stuff-):
2    class Meta:
3       abstract = True
4    -stuff-
5 
6    def myMethod(-stuff-):
7       try:
8          context = self.myChildMethod(-stuff-)
9       except Exception as e:
10         -display the error from e, and log it-
```

~==~ My child class ~==~

```
1 class ChildClass(MySuperClass):
2    def myChildMethod:
3       -stuff1-
4       -stuff2-
5       -stuff3-
6       return -somestuff-
```

For example, if my error comes from the -stuff2-, I would like to have the information that it comes from the file containing the "ChildClass", at the line 4.

BUT, what I am getting at most ends up being the file of the superclass, at line 8.

the print_stack() looks like this basically :

```
lots of lines of the API I don't understand like base.py line 90570930 in blablabla
File -blablabla- super_view.py, line 8, in myMethod
   traceback.print_stack()
```

So is there a way to climb back to the child class, where the error actually comes from ?

I believe that there should be one but ... I've been searching for a little while, and I am still stuck with this, so if any python expert ( or well experienced with it ^^ ) know this ....

Comment: If you know `stuff2()` generates an exception, and you can edit the code, try this: `try: stuff2()`, and handle exception with: `except: import pdb;pdb.post_mortem()`, this will fire up the debugger at the exact line where the exception was generated.

Comment: Well I do not know that stuff2 is generating the exception, it could be stuff1, stuff3, or anything ( of course I look at recently added things but ... that's not the point ).

I would like to be able to handle that exception in my superclass and not the child class.
Otherwise putting try ~~~ except in every child class would do the job.

Thanks for the answer still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have handled the exception in parent class. You have two alternatives :-

1) catch exception in child class, by putting try..catch around stuff2 and log it.
2) if you are catching exception in parent class, then reraise exception in the catch block of parent class using

```
raise e, None, sys.exec_info()[2]
```

and put try catch in stuff2 in child class, as I said in point#1.

Comment: so basically, without catching it in the child class, there is no way to get the information that I am looing for ? I guess that I cannot be that lazy maybe =(

Comment: May be there're other hectic ways to do it, but it'll make your code less intuitive and decreases its flexibility. Like you can access the execution stack and find the caller function of super class function and in this way you can get information about stuff2, but i'll not recommend you to do that.

Comment: Well, using

    type(self).__name__ 

I already access the child class name.

Ok thank you, it can't  be helped then, I will add try ~ catch statement in all my child class I think.